# Woocommerce - How to check product type in plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

I'm pretty new to wordpress/woocommerce and just started playing with creating a custom plugin.

So far I have I have added my custom woocommerce settings via the api.

I've run into a problem where I want to add a custom field on a single product in the product data tab.

I managed to display it using the following code:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', array( $this, 'cuzd_general_fields' ) );
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', array( $this, 'cuzd_general_fields_save') );
```

However now I need to check if the product type is simple or variation.
I tried the following:

```php
$product = new WC_Product( get_the_ID() );
        if( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ) {
          //
}
```

However I get an error:

```php
 Fatal error: Class 'WC_Product' not found in ....
```

I have a good feeling I'm trying to initiate the Product class before its been called.
I most likely have the whole format of the class plugin wrong.
Any reading material with good instruction / best practice would be appreciated.

Otherwise if the above is a simple fix please let me know.

Answer (score 28):

The earliest you could expect to access any Woo classes would be the `woocommerce_loaded` hook which is now fired in the `plugins_loaded` hook. If you are saving on the `woocommerce_process_product_meta` hook then any callback there would have all the classes properly loaded. If you are testing outside of that callback (and not attached to any hook at all.... it would be possible for the classes to not all be properly loaded.

Additionally, if you are attempting to call `get_the_ID()` before the `WP_Post` object has been set up you won't get a correct value.

A more complete `cuzd_general_fields_save` routine would look like:

```
/**
 * Save meta box data.
 *
 * @param int     $post_id WP post id.
 */
public function cuzd_general_fields_save( $post_id ) {

    $_product = wc_get_product( $post_id );

    if( $_product->is_type( 'simple' ) ) {
    // do stuff for simple products
    } else {
    // do stuff for everything else
    }

    $_product->save();

}
```

An update for Woo 3.0 would be to use the `woocommerce_admin_process_product_object` so you no longer need to instantiate the product object or run `save()` as Woo will handle that in core.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', array( $this, 'cuzd_general_fields_save') );
```

and the callback would then be modified to:

```
/**
 * Save meta box data.
 *
 * @param obj $_product WC_Product.
 */
public function cuzd_general_fields_save( $_product ) {

    if( $_product->is_type( 'simple' ) ) {
    // do stuff for simple products
    } else {
    // do stuff for everything else
    }

}
```

Comment: For me at least the variation product type is "variable", not "variation". It may have changed since the original answer but I think this is worth noting for future reference.

Comment: @Tuure Variable and variation both exist. The product type "variable" means it is the parent product that holds multiple "variation" product children. The variations don't show up as separate products in the product list but are actually product posts of their own.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: But if the class is not found why the issue is with the argument? Are you sure this is the right answer?

Comment: I Love SO, 5 years old Question & Answer helped me, Cheers

Answer (score 12):

Here's one way to check the product type without creating an instance of the product:

```
$product_type = get_the_terms( $product_id,'product_type')[0]->slug;
```

Comment: Upvoting to get better reach. I was looking for the exact thing.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to simply check the value of the posted `select`. You can then:

```
$product_type = $_POST['product-type'];

if ( $product_type == 'simple' ) {
 // do what you want
}
```